# Getting linkage error in web logic server while doing roll restart

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, hazelcast, weblogic12c

Getting below error after doing roll restart. To resolve this issue & to up the application running currently we are doing complete server restart.

**Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface
method "com.hazelcast.map.IMap.getLocalMapStats()Lcom/hazelcast/map/LocalMapStats;"
the class loader (instance of ) of the current class, java/lang/Object, and
the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/hazelcast/map/IMap,
have different Class objects for the type**